# Whichever make the script more slowly (I have two choices)

Tags: php

I have table in database named ads, this table contains data about each ad.
I want to get that data from table to display ad.

Now, I have two choices:

1. Either get all data from table and store it in array, and then , I will treat with this array to display each ad in its position `by using loops`.
2. Or access to table directly and get each ad data to display it, note this way will consume more queries to database.

Which one is the best way, and not make the script more slow ?

Comment: The less queries you do to your database the better, so go for your first option.

Comment: Whenever you think you only have two options, you are usually overlooking something. Like using a more efficient SQL query to only get what you want from the database. See answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most Cases #1 is better.

Because, if you can select the data (smallest, needed set) in one query, 
then you have less roundtrips to the database server.

Accessing Array or Objectproperties (from Memory) are usually faster than DB Queries.
You could also consider to prepare your Data and don't mix `fetching` with `view` output.

The second Option "select on demand" could make sense if you need to "lazy load",
maybe because you can or want to recognize client properties, like viewport.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want a direct answer. 
which one is best way,the way Number 1 or the way Number 2 ?

Comment: I will use my first downvote for this. You are saying that getting all the data from a table and storing it in an array is "in most cases better"? Perhaps this can be the case during development but once you go to production and the first 5 million ads are inserted into the database, your db administrator is going to come for you.

Comment: mmhhh..., what did i say?  
please don't quote one part without context.
i said the smallest, needed set (result of _one_ query): 
select with conditions and a limit (preferable indices on where columns) are basic sql knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to highlight the following part:

> get all data from table and store it in array

You do not need to store all rows into an array. You could also take an iterator that represents the resultset and then use that one.

Depending on the database object you use this is often the less memory-intensive variant. Also you would run only one query here which is preferable.

The iterator is actually common with modern database result objects.

Additionally this is helpful to decouple the view code from the actual database interaction and you can also defer to do the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want a direct answer. 
which one is best way,the way Number 1 or the way Number 2  or ?

Comment: I think @pce was pretty clear on that, right? My answer is just to broaden your mind, but looks like you don't want that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should minimize the amount of queries but you should also try to minimize the amount of data you actually get from the database.

So: Get only those ads that you are actually displaying. You could for example use `columnPK IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` to get those ads.

A notable exception: If your application is centered around "ads" and you need them pretty much everywhere, and/or they don't consume much memory, and/or there aren't too many adds, it might be better performance-wise to store all (or a subset) of your ads in an array.

Above all: `Measure, measure, measure`!

It is very, very hard to predict which algorithm will be most efficient. Often you implement something "because it will be more efficient" only to find out later that your optimization is actually slowing down your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want a direct answer. 
which one is best way,the way Number 1 or the way Number 2 ?

Comment: Measuring both ways is the `only` way to be certain. Which way will be fastest can depend on a gazillion things: Which database? What indexes are present? How much data are we talking about? How do the select statement(s) look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to run a PHP script with the least amount of database queries possible. Whenever you query the database, a request must be sent to the database (usually) over the network, and your script will idle until the request came back.

You should, however, make sure not to request any more data from the database than necessary. So try to filter as much in the WHERE clause as possible instead of requesting the whole table and then picking individual rows on the PHP layer.

We could help with writing that SQL query when you tell us how your table looks and how you want to select which ads to display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want a direct answer. 
which one is best way,the way Number 1 or the way Number 2 ?

Comment: When you haven't got more ads in the database than you want to embed into the website you are displaying right now, the first one is better. When you need to pick one or more ads from a large selection, both options are equally awful and you need to be willing to be taught how to write SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have Benefited from your answer also.